# Add <span> tag in the middle of paragraph if :contains() match the text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, contains

I am trying to add a html tag like `<span></span>` around the text matches using `:contains()`.
The `<p>` inside this code is dynamic, not static. So I want a dynamic jQuery that can detect word using `:contains()`, and if it match, will add html tag `<span>` around it. Here is my code, I am trying to detect word "AND" and wrap `<span>` around it so I can add css/class to that "AND" word.

`<div class="bg-text">
   <p>
      JIMMY AND LILY
   </p>
</div>`

I want it to be like this

`<div class="bg-text">'
   <p>
      JIMMY <span class="bold">AND</span> LILY
   </p>
</div>`

Comment: Is there any chance that the paragraph will contain other markup, or will it be **purely** text? I suspect you're going to get a fair number of answers assuming just text (or that it's okay to wipe out and recreate elements, losing any handlers they may have attached to them).

Comment: It will be purely text, I just want to change the css property to the specific text match. This process will be automatic, so no triggering by user. Is that possible to wipe out just the text "AND" for this example? and recreate it.

Comment: I've tried to add class using the :contains() if the string is match. But I have found the answer for my problem. Anyway thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind wiping out the content of the relevant paragraphs and recreating it, then:

```
$('div p').each(function() {
    var originalText = this.innerHTML;
    var newText = originalText.replace(
                         /\band\b/gi,
                         '<span class="bold">$&</span>'
                     );
    if (originalText !== newText) {
        this.innerHTML = newText;
    }
});
```

How that works:

1. We find all the relevant paragraphs.
2. We loop through them with `each`.
3. We get the markup for their contents.
4. We do the replacement. `\b` in the regex stands for "word boundary" so we don't have things like "stand" and such getting messed up. The `$&` in the replacement string is whatever we matched, so that "AND" is replaced with "AND" and "and" is replaced with "and".
5. If there were any changes, we write them back to the element. If there *aren't*, we don't do that, because it's unnecessary overhead.

Caveats:

- If you have nested instances of these paragraphs, you'll get the spans occurring more than once (because we'll process the text twice, once for the outer and again for the inner paragraph). You're not supposed to nest paragraphs, though, so...
- This *wipes out and recreates* the contents of the paragraphs in question. If you have event handlers on any elements in them, those will get detached. (You said in comments on the question that was okay, I'm just highlighting it.)

Comment: you mean wiped out the "AND" word and recreate html for it? 
Can you explain /\b \b/
and where is $& came from.

Sorry for being a newbie, I AM a newbie, trying to understand every single line :)

Comment: Ow thanks, will read it throughly, I tested it on my website, and it works. Thank you very much @T.J. Crowder. Really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize the `.replace()` function for this:

```
$('div p').html($('div p').html().replace(/AND/gi, '<span class="bold">AND</span>'));
```

But of course you will have to work out issues such as this string:

```
<div class="bg-text"> <p> JIMMY AND LILY'S BAND ARE WAITING UP AGAINST THE GRAND STAND LOOKING FOR A HAND WITH THEIR INSTRUMENTS </p> </div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4LKmV/)

Comment: You probably want boundary markers on that, so you don't replace (oh, say) "Ferdinand" or "standing" or... And rather than wiping out all of the elements inside every paragraph inside a div on the page, perhaps limit the carnage to just the ones that need updating.

Comment: WOW, you just solved my problem man! Thank you very much!

Can I ask what is the "gi" after the /AND/ for?

Comment: @sanbrons: `g` stands for "global" (not just the first match), and `i` means "case-insensitive". But be forewarned, this will replaces "Jack and Jill" with "Jack <span class="bold">AND</span> Jill" (in caps).

Comment: Ow T.J. Crowder, It did change, I tried "BAND" in the paragraph. hmm... can you tell me how? I am quite confusing :P

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

Comment: Anyway thanks @user2191572, I really appreciate your help :). both answers is useful for me, However, I just made my account today, I afraid I cant vote up both of your answers :) cheers

Comment: No sweat man, good luck with your website. Always use the right tool for the job. Some day you might end using this simpler solution if it applies :)