# jQuery : match keyword(will be an array) and set span tag to it

Tags: jquery, regex, match, element

I have some paragraph inside a div like this :

```
<div class=entry-content>
<p>Jhony bought a laptop for £1,500.00</p>
<p>Alex bought a desk for £500.00</p>
</div>
```

I want to add span tag with class="price" for each of price, this is what I want to:

```
<div class=entry-content>
<p>Jhony bought a laptop for <span class="price">£1,500.00<span></p>
<p>Alex bought a desk for <span class="price">£500.00<span></p>
</div>
```

I already solve how to find/match price using regular expression, but I am stuck how to add the span tag for each of price.

this is my jquery code to match the price :

```
var text = jQuery('div.entry-content').text();
var select=text.match(/£(?!0\.00)\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)/g);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('.entry-content p').html(function (i, html) {
    //the regex is not complete
    return html.replace(/(£(\d{1,3},)*\d+\.\d{2})/, '<span class="price">$1</span>')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/22Yv5/)

Comment: Hi Arun, thank you for the answer, it works! :)
I also found same solution from this question >> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845892/add-span-tag-in-the-middle-of-paragraph-if-contains-match-the-text-using-jq?rq=1)